# How to set different visibility properties for repeated items

Tags: c#, asp.net

I Have a user custom control with a repeater that has a calendar and a button that should toggle visibility for each repeated calendar.

```
    <asp:Repeater ID="DateRepeater" runat="server" 
          DataSourceID="DateSource" OnItemCommand="DateRepeater_ItemCommand" OnPreRender="DateRepeater_PreRender">
          <ItemTemplate>
 <tr>
        <td class="auto-style8">
            <asp:ImageButton ID="CalendarButtonRef" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/img/calendar.png" OnClick="ShowCalendar_Click" />
                <asp:Calendar ID = "RefCalendar" Width="176" runat="server" OnSelectionChanged="Calendar_SelChanged"></asp:Calendar>
        </td>
    </tr>
          </ItemTemplate>
          <FooterTemplate>
              </table>
          </FooterTemplate>
      </asp:Repeater>
```

In the codebehind I am trying to target the clicked image button on the same repeated item

```
 protected void ShowCalendar_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        ImageButton btnSender = (ImageButton)sender;
        String TragetCalendarID = btnSender.UniqueID.Remove(19) + "RefCalendar";
        if (Page.IsPostBack) 
        {
            Calendar TargetCalendar;
            foreach (RepeaterItem rpt in DateRepeater.Items)
            {
                if (rpt.FindControl("RefCalendar").UniqueID == TragetCalendarID) 
                {
                    Trace.Write(rpt.FindControl("RefCalendar").UniqueID);
                    Trace.Write(rpt.FindControl("RefCalendar").GetType().ToString());
                    TargetCalendar = (Calendar)rpt.FindControl(TragetCalendarID);
                    if (TargetCalendar.Visible == false) 
                    {
                        TargetCalendar.Visible = true;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                     TargetCalendar.Visible = false;

                }
            }
        }
```

I manage to cast the target Calendar and in the trace I get the object as a calendar but when I try to get the visibility property it says that the object reference is not set to an instance of an object.

What is missing in my code?

Comment: I'd suggest you step through the code and see if the find control section actually finds anything, since it's saying Object Not Set.. Seems like it's not finding anything and then you're trying to set essentially nothing to visible = true.

Comment: Is it feasible for you to implement the functionality in JQuery?

Answer (score 0):

This is how the function then works, if referring to the object by its ID with FindControl it works. I was trying to cast the object to a calendar and use it as as a variable but it doesn't work like that.

This is the working code

```
    protected void ShowCalendar_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    ImageButton btnSender = (ImageButton)sender;
    String TragetCalendarID = btnSender.UniqueID.Remove(19) + "RefCalendar";
    if (Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        foreach (RepeaterItem rpt in DateRepeater.Items)
        {
            if (rpt.FindControl("RefCalendar").UniqueID == TragetCalendarID)
            {
                if (rpt.FindControl("RefCalendar").Visible == false)
                {
                    rpt.FindControl("RefCalendar").Visible = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    rpt.FindControl("RefCalendar").Visible = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```